# python read data from file and calculate result

Tags: python

i want to store some values in a python file like blew
here is my abc.py file

```
{
  21:"This field is required",
  22:"Value can't be null",
  23:"other custom message",
}
```

then i want to calculate code from a given string in a python function.
example:

```
def calculate_code(error_message):
    #process error_message and read data from abc.py file
    #calculate error_code
    return eror_code
```

like if i have error_message = "Value can't be null" then i ll get error_code = 22.

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: u wan to store the values in text file or in a varibale in pythonfile

Comment: i want to store values in a separate file so that i can change or update it easily. it can be text file or python file or json file.

Comment: Do you really want a human to enter the full error message to get the code?  A human might prefer to do a search like "null" instead of "value can't be null" and get a list of codes and their messages.

Comment: its not for humans .... the error_messages are already defined ....its just for internal processing.

Answer (score 1):

A sensible solution would be to define a cache class (based on a dictionary) from messages to error codes. This is not a complete solution, but this provides a skeleton:

from datetime import datetime
from os import stat
import time

```
class Cache(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._populate_cache()

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        if self._check_file_updated():
           self._populate_cache()
        return self._cache[name]

    def _populate_cache(self):
        self._populate_time = time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
        self._cache = read_file_as_dict(self._filename)
        print "debug: updated cache"

    def _check_file_updated(self):
        return stat(self._filename).st_mtime > self._populate_time


def read_file_as_dict(filename):
    # needs an implementation: just simulating
    return { "Blown up": 25, "Warning": 31 }
```

Usage:

```
cache = Cache("test")
>>> cache["Blown up"]
25
>>> cache["Blown up"]
25
```

Now I touch the "test" file:

```
>>> cache["Blown up"]
debug: updated cache
25
```

Comment: i want to store values in a separate file so that i can change or update it easily.

Comment: It does not matter, then define a dictionary with caching functionality: on access to values it will check if the file was changed since last load, if yes reload it to dictionary, but otherwise read a value from the dictionary

Comment: See the updated answer. You just need to add loading data from file to a dict and checking the timestamp of the file. Should be easy :) And well, you would need to check the rest of syntax as I cannot execute incomplete code

Comment: Ok, now it is full and working up to the point of reading your custom data from file into a dict... Check this up